# How to detect which dependency in a project uses Proxy in order to activate React Native Hermes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-hermes

I'm trying to activate Hermes in a react-native project in order to improve the startup time and memory usage but when I try running it I get the following Error:

> RefrenceError: Property 'Proxy' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes

I'm aware that Hermes does not support Proxy usage yet so I'm trying to identify which of my dependencies use it in order to remove it.

I've tried searching for the `Proxy` keyword on my repo but I couldn't identify any reference to it. How can I detect which dependencies use it?

My dependencies are following:

```js
"dependencies": {
  "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.5",
  "@eva-design/eva": "^2.0.0",
  "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.2.2",
  "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^6.4.0",
  "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.4.0",
  "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.4.0",
  "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^6.4.0",
  "@react-native-firebase/functions": "^6.4.0",
  "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.4.0",
  "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^6.4.0",
  "@segment/analytics-react-native": "1.1.0",
  "@segment/analytics-react-native-amplitude": "1.1.0",
  "@sentry/react-native": "^1.4.5",
  "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.0.0",
  "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.0.0",
  "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "^4.2.6",
  "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.5",
  "apollo-cache-persist": "^0.1.1",
  "apollo-client": "^2.6.8",
  "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
  "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.20",
  "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.13",
  "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
  "apollo-link-retry": "^2.2.16",
  "apollo-link-ws": "^1.0.20",
  "apollo-utilities": "^1.3.3",
  "graphql": "^15.0.0",
  "graphql-tag": "^2.10.3",
  "lodash": "^4.17.15",
  "moment": "^2.24.0",
  "phone": "^2.4.3",
  "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
  "react": "16.9.0",
  "react-native": "0.61.4",
  "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
  "react-native-check-notification-enable": "^1.3.0",
  "react-native-config-reader": "^4.1.0",
  "react-native-console-time-polyfill": "^1.2.1",
  "react-native-device-info": "^5.4.1",
  "react-native-fast-image": "^8.1.2",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.1",
  "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
  "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^1.9.0",
  "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
  "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.1.0",
  "react-native-image-view": "^2.1.8",
  "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.1",
  "react-native-keycode": "^1.0.5",
  "react-native-modal": "^11.5.4",
  "react-native-permissions": "^2.0.8",
  "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.9",
  "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
  "react-native-root-siblings": "^4.0.6",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.2",
  "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
  "react-native-svg": "^9.13.3",
  "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
  "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
  "react-navigation-switch-transitioner": "^0.1.1",
  "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.6.0",
  "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
  "redux": "^4.0.4",
  "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
  "reselect": "^4.0.0",
  "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
  "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.16",
  "uuid": "^3.3.2"
},
```

Comment: Doesn't the stack trace point it out? I did a casual `grep -rw Proxy node_modules` and browsed through the results, and `@ui-kitten/eva-icons` and `jest-util` stood out

Comment: Unfortunately No :( https://i.imgur.com/h9Zdy35.png

Comment: jest-util it's only for testing purposes, right? It should affect it. I'll test the `@ui-kitten/eva-icons` thing. Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that the `index.js` the first stack element mentions would be the problem, but unfortunately the redbox doesn't show the path and you have over a thousand files with that name. Maybe `adb logcat` will give you the full path including the module name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ui-kitten` is not fully compatible with React Native Hermes, should just remove it from your project.

Answer (score 0):

By the end of the day the package that was causing it was `@ui-kitten/eva-icons`. I just had to remove it and it worked.